# Need replacement for "Favorite de voyage"

Tags: vocabulaire

I am unaware of French Language but I need francisation for Mobile App Development.
I need a small word (small string) for the phrase *Favorite Trip* (in English). I translated it through Google translator and got the phrase *Favorite de voyage* (in French). But I want smaller phrase than this.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: "*Favorite de voyage*" isn't right for "*Favourite Trip*", so there's no issue about this specific example, but in general, you should expect French expressions to be slightly longer than English expressions, in particular because you can't glue nouns together in French (you'd have to use the longer expression, for example "*room temperature*" -> "*temperature of the room*" -> "*température de la pièce*"). You should take that into account for the layout of your user interface.

Comment: *Maybe* **heavy** rewriting could make something out of this question, but as it stands, it's based on wrong premises, answerable by a dictionary, and would look like homework if it wasn't so obviously just work. Also I'm not sure about this site's interest about "short strings". I would've been glad to see this happen on chat.

Answer (score 10):

I don't quite understand why you want it smaller, but anyway *favorite de voyage* is gibberish. What you mean is probably *voyage favori* or *voyage préféré*.

Comment: The string I mentioned i.e. _favorite de voyage_ is not fitting in the label of Mobile App. So I needed the change.

Answer (score 6):

If your context is clear enough (i.e. the user will understand it is about a trip), just use *Favori*.

Answer (score 5):

The correct translation would be “*Voyage favori”* it's already slightly shorter than your current string.

Answer (score 5):

Depending of you context "Voyage favori" could be an adequate answer.

If you are developping an app in ITS, you should consider "Trajet favori" as an alternative.